# C++ SFML Text flickers when drawn

Tags: c++, events, while-loop, event-handling, sfml

I have an SFML `RenderWindow`, and when it closes, it'll display a confirmation message. I've run into this same problem a lot of times: the confirmation message (an `sf::Text`) is drawn when the `Event::Closed` is called, but it only stays when the event is called; I think till the click on the close button is registered (calling the close event); disappears in a flash (does that have something to do with the speed of C++?). How can I solve this? The text should be displayed after it's drawn, and shouldn't disappear, after calling the close event.

Here is the code (in `main.cpp`):

```cpp
while (app.isOpen())
    {

        // Process events
        sf::Event event;
        while (app.pollEvent(event))
        {

            // Close window : exit
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                app.clear();
                Text close("Are you sure you want to close this?", Arial);
                app.draw(close);
                close.setCharacterSize(40);
                close.setPosition(300, 300);
                app.display();
            }

        }

        // Clear screen
        app.clear();

        // Draw the sprite
        app.draw(sprite);
        app.draw(text);
        text.setPosition(500, 500);

        // Update the window
        app.display();
    }
```

The workaround gives me an error:
I made a function to do the work, but it gives me this error:

> error: use of deleted function 'sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const sf::RenderWindow&)'.

[Here](https://justpaste.it/4ucb3) is the code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try reading your code aloud: "while there are events to be processed, do stuff. Afterwards, clear the screen and render the rest of the program.

Comment: You need to restructure your code so the intent to close is recorded somewhere, and then you can render the close text as part of – or instead of – your regular game loop.

Comment: @Botje, yes! I thought of it but was not sure how to go about it. I made a function to do the work, but it gives me this error: `use of deleted function 'sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const sf::RenderWindow&)'`. [Here](https://justpaste.it/4ucb3) is the code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70460772/edit) to keep the discussion contained on this site.

Comment: @Botje, I've added it!

Comment: No, extracting that code to a function does not change the fundamental problem.

Comment: @Botje, oh. I'm not sure how the while loop or SFML's methods work. Could you please explain them or suggest what should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep an explicit variable with the state of the game, and change your game code based on that:

```
enum class GameState { Playing, Closing };
GameState phase = GameState::Playing;
```

```
while (app.isOpen()) {

    // Process events
    sf::Event event;
    while (app.pollEvent(event)) {

        // Close window : exit
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
            phase = GameState::Closing;
        }

    }

    // Clear screen
    app.clear();

    if (phase == GameState::Closing) {
        Text close("Are you sure you want to close this?", Arial);
        close.setCharacterSize(40);
        close.setPosition(300, 300);
        app.draw(close);
    } else if (phase == GameState::Playing) {
        app.draw(sprite);
        app.draw(text);
        text.setPosition(500, 500);
    }

    // Update the window
    app.display();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Till now, I didn't understand that only through events can any change be made (I was thinking this was like Tkinter where interactions with widgets can change such states of the program but there are no widgets!) to the program's UI.